# Replace id foreign key with username in query result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have this query which works:

```
SELECT id, SUM(points) AS points
FROM leaderboard 
WHERE roundtime BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP
GROUP BY id ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 25
```

It might return something like this:

```
id    points
------------
15    430
17    278
16    92
```

However, instead of having id in the results, I want to replace it with the username that id corresponds with (from the users table)

Users table:

```
id   username
-------------
15   Frank
16   Joe
17   Andy
```

So that the first query results in:

```
username  points
----------------
Frank     430
Andy      278
Joe       92
```

I tried using subqueries but couldn't quite get it working and it was getting messy. Is there a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a Plain JOIN to do what you need. Don't use subqueries it will make your SQL slower than it needs to be:

```
SELECT u.username, SUM(l.points) AS points
  FROM leaderboard l
        INNER JOIN yourUserTable u
                ON l.id = u.ColumnNameForTheUserId
 WHERE roundtime BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours' 
                     AND LOCALTIMESTAMP
 GROUP BY u.username 
 ORDER BY points DESC 
 LIMIT 25
```

Comment: This was throwing an error until I changed `GROUP BY l.id` to `GROUP BY l.id, u.username, l.points`. It said those two `must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Ops, my bad, I just forgot to change the group by. Sorry.

Comment: Ok just making sure that is the correct fix and will return the proper data.

Comment: No need for the `l.id` on the group by since it is not on the select list.

Comment: Ok. You might want to add `l.points` to the `GROUP BY` for future readers.

Comment: No, don't do that, you can't add the column that is used by an aggregation function like `sum` on the group by list. Because than you will have wrong values. The group by separates values of the grouped columns, if you add the aggregated column on the group by list you don't need the sum or even the group by on your queries.

Comment: But your version doesn't work? It just errors out with `ORDER BY l.points DESC ERROR` `ERROR: column "l.points" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Oooooh, that's becase the ORDER BY, sorry. You can't use a column that is not on the select list on the order by list. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your query the sub-query. I joined the users table to your query:

```
SELECT p.username, q.points from(
(SELECT id, SUM(points) AS points
FROM leaderboard 
WHERE roundtime BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP
GROUP BY id ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 25
) q 
LEFT JOIN users_table p
ON p.id = q.id
```

The above is to demonstrate how to extract the information you want from the query you already built.

I hope that helps explain what is happening with this query combining the above (this is more concise):

```
SELECT p.username, q.points 
FROM leaderboard q 
LEFT JOIN users_table p
ON p.id = q.id
WHERE roundtime BETWEEN LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '24 hours' AND    LOCALTIMESTAMP
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY points 
DESC LIMIT 25
```

[Here is an example of this query](http://rextester.com/TBKDE40829)